# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Window is a dull color

Tags: 12.04

When you open up Google Chrome in MS Windows the white background is a brilliant white, but in Ubuntu its a dull white color.  Why is this and is it normal?  Is there a way to adjust the change this to have the same if not similar defined characteristics as Windows?

[image: Chrome Under Ubuntu]

[image: Chrome Under Windows]

Comment: I just installed Chrome, and the background is brilliant white.  Can you maybe include an image?

Comment: How do I do that :)

Comment: Upload it some where and give me the link, and I will include it for you.

Comment: This is the windows screen shot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/windowsscreen.png/

Comment: This is the Ubuntu Screenshot:  http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8687/ubuntuscreen.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, the white in both your screenshots look the same to me. This leads me to think that it's a color calibration difference between Ubuntu and Windows.

Look here for instructions on how to calibrate your screen, also how to change the gamma settings, which may be enough for what you want:

[How to calibrate the monitor on an Ubuntu system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9443/how-to-calibrate-the-monitor-on-an-ubuntu-system)