# Calibrate Printer Color by Hand

Tags: printing, color-management

How does one calibrate the color of a printer by hand or by eye. More specifically, the printer just has to match the monitor, it doesn't matter if they are both perfect.

Is there a way that you can print a test image, and then on a monitor have it adjust the color til it matches the printed version. Then when you print, it would do the opposite transformation , so that it matches the monitor?

Comment: Hi Comrade, is that for shape formed image or photograph image?

Answer (score 1):

Little theory. For each device, printer or monitor there is a ICC profile (ICC profile is a set of data that characterizes a color input or output device, or a color space (C) Wiki). As I understand you want to change only monitor settings.

There is a usefull [tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnome-color-manager/) for managing ICC profiles, for sure it will help with monitor, check if it can help with printer.

Some of this answers could be useful (especialy if you can deal with german) [related topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9443/how-to-calibrate-the-monitor-on-an-ubuntu-system)