# How do I apply color profiles in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, color-management

In GNOME, you can use GNOME Color Manager. But how can I do this in Xfce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the color manager on xfce by running `colormgr`.

If you want to apply a color profile:

```
sudo apt-get install xcalib -y
```

Apply an ICM file with:

```
xcalib profilename.icm
```

Revert the changes with `xcalib -c`.

Note that the change won't stay upon reboot, so you'll need to add the `xcalib profilename.icm` command to Startup Applications.

Comment: You'll need xiccd too to get the full profile running, see https://askubuntu.com/q/427821/25639

Answer (score 1):

Search in Settings > Color profiles. Select the monitor, click Add. If it's not on the list, click the folder icon to import one. Select it from the list, click ok and make sure it's enabled.

Comment: This is indeed the correct modern way to do it. I would also add that, according to the Xfce docs (docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/color), as well as personal experience, you should also make sure that xiccd is installed, in order for the profile to actually be applied.