# Does Ubuntu has a MacOS like monitor color calibration app?

Tags: color-management

I do not have monitor color calibration hardware and I like to use monitor calibration app that is similar MacOS on Ubuntu, is there one?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9443/how-to-calibrate-the-monitor-on-an-ubuntu-system not exactly like mac, but their are calibration solutions provided here

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh first I run xfce instead of gnome, second that app only swap color profiles and doesn't do anything to calibrate.

Comment: Their are 5 answers on that question including apps that work on XFCE I think, if they don't work then update your question on exactly how you want it and why they didn't fit your requirements. The more information you give the more attention your question gets

Comment: No. There isn't. All of the answers are about swapping color profiles instead of calibration. These are two very different questions, the other thread should change the question to how to swap color profiles under Ubuntu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/236516/665251 see if this answer works

Comment: Again this is about "How to set system display color profiles" instead "Calibrating colors with human eyes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an app for that:

DisplayCAL

Formerly known as dispcalGUI

Open Source Display Calibration and Characterization powered by Argyll CMS

https://displaycal.net/

Answer (score 4):

The thing that you're asking seems impossible but you can use Websites that offer display calibration by using *Human input*

and then you can make changes to your color profiles the way you want and test it again until you get it right. this is how I did it at least.

[The Lagom LCD monitor test pages](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/)

The link above is one of many websites that offer this functionality. There are lot of other answers available that shows you how to edit color profile files.

---

*I don't know how the Mac OS calibration works so I can't suggest an App that is similar to it, and in my opinion many people around **here** don't know how the Mac OS calibration works, so if you give a little more details explaining how the Mac OS App works then maybe someone will come up with better answer than mine*

Comment: Basically it is an app that show you these images and let you pick the best result and then generates color profile for you.

Comment: @AeroWindwalker Then you'll need to do some more work in Ubuntu, i Guess