# Boost saturation Intel HD Graphics

Tags: intel

I have a terrible 1366 x 768 display on my laptop, so by default the colors are very washed  out.  In Windows there is a "Intel Graphics Control Panel" where I can edit the contrast, brightness and saturation but there is nothing like this in Ubuntu.  I even went through the effort of doing a complete install of Windows 10 in attempt to export a color profile from Windows into Linux, but I tested it in the Live USB and it still has terrible colors.  Does Linux seriously have no way to do this simple of a task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calibrate the monitor on an Ubuntu system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9443/how-to-calibrate-the-monitor-on-an-ubuntu-system)

Comment: No.  I don’t want to calibrate and spend $1000 on a colorimeter.I just want to boost the saturation.  Does Ubuntu have this basic feature other OS’s would consider standard?

Comment: Why do you believe you need any additional hardware?  I would not recommend it based on the quality of your display.